# How to test whether a symbol is added to CFLAGS in Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile

If I add one line below in a Makefile:

```
CFLAGS += -DMY_SYMBOL
```

How to test whether 'MY_SYMBOL' is defined in a subdirectory Makefile? It seems the following doesn't work:

```
ifdef MY_SYMBOL
#do something
endif
```

Thanks.

The following doesn't seem to work either:

```
define symbol_in_cflags_check
@echo $(1)
@echo $(2)
ifeq ($(1), $(2))
SUBDIRS := music
endif
endef

RESULT := $(foreach SYMBOL, $(shell echo $(CFLAGS)), $(call symbol_in_cflags_check, $(SYMBOL), -DIN_MUSIC))
```

Comment: Your first approach (`ifdef...`) works for me, in GNUMake 3.81. Which version of Make are you using? And could you give us a complete example?

Comment: Wait... Are you trying to test whether `MY_SYMBOL` is *defined*, or whether it's *in `CFLAGS`?*

Comment: @Beta, Yes, I want to know whether MY_SYMBOL(IN_MUSIC in the 2nd case) is added to   CFLAGS  , so I can make a decision whether to compile some source files accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ifneq (,$(filter MY_SYMBOL,$(CFLAGS)))
# it is in CFLAGS, so do something
else
# it is NOT in CFLAGS, so do something else
endif
```

Comment: I've tried this, but unfortunately, there is another symbol called MY_SYMBOL_XXX also defined in CFLAGS, so findstring always returns true. That's why I try to use foreach and call a user defined function.

Comment: @dejunl: I should have thought of that. Correcting my answer... Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

if it's just a quick test you want, add a line to the subdirectory Makefile, like

```
echo ${CFLAGS} | grep MY_SYMBOL && echo "yes, it's there" || echo "no, not there"
```

and you should see the result when you do the make.